# Recyclerview fully scroll to position

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

My recyclerview should open the first item closed. To this end, I wrote these lines.

```
 LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
 llm.scrollToPosition(1);
 paletteRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

I want to check if it is possible to scroll to position 1 fully. If my recyclerview is small I must open it without closing the first item. How can I check it?

Comment: check if `recyclerView.getHeight() > recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange` and if this is true then do not scroll to position 1.

Comment: I've checked these two parameters returning 0. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to know if there are items to scroll in RecyclerView. So you can check as below after setting the adapter to the recyclerView.

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int recyclerViewheight = recyclerView.getHeight();
            int totalChildViewsHeight = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange();
            if (recyclerViewheight > totalChildViewsHeight) {
                //there is no scroll (there are no more items to scroll)
            } else {
                //there is scroll (there are items to scroll)
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've checked these two parameters returning 0. What can be the reason?

Comment: are you doing it on `recyclerView.post()` and after setting adapter?

Comment: No, Why I must do recyclerView.post()?

Comment: Because at the time of your call, the recyclerView will not be rendered on screen so you can't get the height. If you do it on `post()`, the operation in runnable will be done in the next pass after rendering.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code...

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new YourAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```